# Can you get yourself into an unwinnable situation by missing one time only clues in Blade Runner?

Tags: blade-runner

In Blade Runner for the PC, is it possible to get yourself into an unwinnable situation by missing a clue that's only available at a specific time or under a specific set of circumstances?

For example, are there any items that are required in order to complete the game that you have to obtain the first time that you enter an area, which will be gone if you try to return to it later on. Thus making it impossible to win the game.

Comment: Not putting this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure but I believe that is also the point of the Deckard's Photo Inspector, it allows you to scan for items that you did miss.

Comment: What is Deckard's photo inspector?

Comment: the grid thing that you scan photos with that does the zoom and enhance thing

Comment: In the localization for my language it's called the Esper machine?